# Unable to enable php-yaml for php 8.0 in ddev

Tags: docker, drupal, yaml, php-extension, ddev

After creating directory structure for Drupal9,

```
ddev config --project-type=drupal9 --docroot=web --create-docroot
```

i created the project, a Drupal distribution [Varbase Starter Kit](https://www.drupal.org/project/varbase) in this directory using ddev:

```
ddev composer create Vardot/varbase-project:~9 --no-dev --no-interaction
```

I did the necessary configurations and changed the name and docroot (note: Varbase uses the directory called docroot instead of web) of the project in config.yaml
Then while i was trying to install the distribution via browser i had a warning telling me that PHP extension YAML is missing.

So according to [instructions](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customizing-images/) in ddev documentation i added the package to Docker image by adding the following line to config.yaml:

```
webimage_extra_packages: [php-yaml]
```

Then in order to enable the extension i created a php directory in .ddev directory and added my configuration with an .ini file that contains the following lines:

```
[PHP]
extension=yaml.so
```

I restarted ddev but YAML extension was still not enabled.
I checked and saw that php-yaml package was successfully installed but was not enabled.
when i list the PHP modules with the command `ddev php -m` yaml is not listed and i get the following warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'yaml.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20200930/yaml.so (/usr/lib/php/20200930/yaml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20200930/yaml.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20200930/yaml.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

It seems that yaml.so file cannot be found (or accessed?) so it cannot be enabled.
How can I fix this?

I'm using Linux Mint (LMDE5) and website is Drupal9 with PHP 8.0, nginx-fpm, mariadb 10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you want is just `php8.0-yaml`, so in `.ddev/config.yaml`:

`webimage_extra_packages: [php8.0-yaml]`

No additional configuration is required (you don't have to change php configuration) just `ddev restart`. After you do that you'll see yaml listed in `ddev php -i`

Comment: Can I suggest the docs are improved here - as it's not super clear here: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/customizing-images/#adding-extra-debian-packages-with-webimage_extra_packages-and-dbimage_extra_packages - that you have to add a specific version (e.g. I got stuck on `php-ssh2` until I found this and realised I needed the more specific `php8.0-ssh2`)

Comment: If you know what you want to say, please click the pencil icon on https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customizing-images and do a PR.